# printing outside of if statement in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am beginner to python and I know this question shows it. Below is my code and question...

```
print("This program tests if the sequence of positive numbers you input are unique")
print("Enter -1 to quit")


def inputvalues():
    firstnumber=int(input("Enter the first number:"))
    Next=0
    sequence=[firstnumber]
    while Next !=-1:
       Next=int(input("Next: "))
       nextvalue=Next
       sequence.append(nextvalue)
       if sequence.count(nextvalue)==1:
          print("The sequence {} is unique!".format(sequence))
       else:
          sequence.count(nextvalue)>1
          print("The sequence {} is NOT unique!".format(sequence))

inputvalues()
```

It is printing the following...

```
This program tests if the sequence of positive numbers you input are unique
Enter -1 to quit
Enter the first number:5
Next: 6
The sequence [6] is unique!
Next: 7
The sequence [6, 7] is unique!
Next: 8
The sequence [6, 7, 8] is unique!
Next: 9
The sequence [6, 7, 8, 9] is unique!
Next: -1
The sequence [6, 7, 8, 9, -1] is unique!
```

I need it to output the following...

```
This program tests if the sequence of positive numbers you input are unique
Enter -1 to quit
Enter the first number: 9
Next: 5
Next: 3
Next: 6
Next: 23
Next: -1
The sequence [9, 5, 3, 6, 23] is unique..
```

How do I print the final line (is unique, not unique) without printing the sequence between the input entries(Next:)?

Answer (score 1):

Dave Costa correctly corrected your code. Here's an alternative solution if you're interested in something shorter:

```
print("This program tests if the sequence of positive numbers you input are unique")
print("Enter -1 to quit")
sequence = list(map(int, iter(lambda: input('Enter a number: '), '-1')))
if len(sequence) == len(set(sequence)):
    print("The sequence %s is unique!" % sequence)
else:
    print("The sequence %s is NOT unique!" % sequence)
```

Sequence with unique numbers:

```
This program tests if the sequence of positive numbers you input are unique
Enter -1 to quit
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: -1
The sequence [2, 4, 5, 1] is unique!
```

Sequence with repeating numbers:

```
This program tests if the sequence of positive numbers you input are unique
Enter -1 to quit
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 23
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: -1
The sequence [3, 5, 23, 5] is NOT unique!
```

Comment: Except that completely changes the logic.

Comment: It does exactly what you want to achieve in your question. What change of logic are you talking about?

Comment: I didn't post the question, and the person did not state the requirements very clearly.  But I believe they want to call the sequence "unique" if it doesn't contain any duplicate values.  Your version only checks whether the *last* number entered is a duplicate.

Comment: In fact, since the loop will terminate only when a -1 is entered, there can never be more than one -1 in the sequence, and therefore your version will always produce "unique" as the output.

Comment: @DaveCosta Thanks. Indeed I misread the OP's intention. Your correction of his code is correct. I've edited my answer to provide an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want to do is check, as each number is entered, whether it is already in the sequence.  If it is, you can immediately declare it "non-unique" and break out of the loop.  Otherwise, you keep going until the user terminates the sequence by ending -1.  If you reach that point, the sequence must be "unique".

```
def inputvalues():
    firstnumber=int(input("Enter the first number:"))
    Next=0
    sequence=[firstnumber]
    while Next !=-1:
       Next=int(input("Next: "))
       nextvalue=Next
       sequence.append(nextvalue)
       if sequence.count(nextvalue)>1:
          print("The sequence {} is NOT unique!".format(sequence))
          break

    print("The sequence {} is unique!".format(sequence))
```

More ideas for you to try:  I don't think the `nextvalue` variable is necessary.  You also need to ensure you don't add the -1 to the sequence.